# Adding string to a retrieved data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can any one help me for this:

```
select round(sum(convert(float, size) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2)
```

There is nothing wrong with the query. The thing here is, I need output as something like `1 GB` like that. Is this possible to get the text 'GB' within the column itself.

Comment: Something like this?

select CAST(round(sum(convert(float,size)/1024/1024/1024),2) AS VARCHAR) + ' GB'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(round(sum(convert(float,size)/1024/1024/1024),2) AS VARCHAR(20)) + UPPER('gb') AS [Size]
```

should do the trick...

Comment: How to get them in uppercase. i can't get them. I have tried in many ways

Comment: you can force the string to upper case with UPPER(), I have updated my answer to show this. If it still doesn't work, maybe there is something forcing the string to lower-case elsewhere?

Comment: Why not write 'GB' instead of upper('gb') ? ;)

Comment: @SQLGeorge that's what I had in the original answer, I changed it in the revision to demonstrate the UPPER() function. I appreciate your answer though ;-), because, well, it's en flique...

Comment: 'en flique' - I will memorize that phrase ;)